# What is the correct way to check nil pointer de-reference?

Tags: list, pointers, go, struct, linked-list

To illustrate the question:

Say you've got the following struct with a method display (value receiver) that is meant to print the contents:

```
type ListNode struct {
    Val  int
    Next *ListNode
}


func (l ListNode) display() {
    for &l != nil {
        fmt.Printf("%v ->", l.Val)
        l = *l.Next
    }
    fmt.Println()
}

func main() {
    num1 := ListNode{2, &ListNode{4, &ListNode{3, nil}}}

    num1.display()
}
```

The above execution will error on the final loop since I've tried to de-reference nil with this output:

```
2 ->4 ->3 ->panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x0 pc=0x109ae6f]
```

However, changing the function to a pointer receiver, it elegantly becomes:

```
func (l *ListNode) display() {
    for l != nil {
        fmt.Printf("%v ->", l.Val)
        l = l.Next
    }
    fmt.Println()
}
```

with a happy output of:

```
2 ->4 ->3 ->
```

As a "newbie" to go, I figured since the `display()` function is read only, it would be best to write the function with a value receiver, but run into this issue. Is there a more elegant solution with a value receiver I'm missing or a better way to de-reference in the original function?

Comment: `l = *l.Next` is the line that gives you troubles. So just don't dereference if `l.Next` is nil.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no point in testing the address of a value receiver to see if it is nil like this:

```
 for &l != nil {
```

Here, `l` is a variable with a value, and it can never be nil.

If you get a pointer receiver, this will do it, and will work even when `l` is nil:

```
func (l *ListNode) display() {
   for trc:=l; trc!=nil; trc=trc.Next {
        fmt.Printf("%v ->", trc.Val)
    }
}
```

If you get a value receiver:

```
func (l ListNode) display() {
   for trc:=&l; trc!=nil; trc=trc.Next {
        fmt.Printf("%v ->", trc.Val)
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks! the above two display examples make sense... one question though. I don't see why the for &l != nil statement is pointless. I'm not checking the variable value of `l`, but rather the address of `l`, which changes in each iteration of the loop, right?

Comment: No, address of `l` never changes. `l` is the copy of the `ListNode`, it has a value, and `&l` always points to that value. When you do `l=*l.Next` you rewrite the contents of that copy with the contents of the next node.

Answer (score 2):

The fact that you have a value receiver doesn't change the fact that you have pointer fields. And you don't need to coerce their form to receiver's form (value/pointer). They can remain pointers. No need to dereference (explicitly).

```
func (l ListNode) display() {
    curNode := &l
    for curNode != nil {
        fmt.Printf("%v ->", curNode.Val)
        curNode = curNode.Next
    }
    fmt.Println()
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The following is a pointer dereference:

```
v = *ptr
```

This will crash if ptr is nil. You check for nil *before* dereferencing.

```
if ptr != nil {
    v = *ptr
    // ...... 
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this in one line? I'm trying to log an input argument in a function. If I log it as-is as a pointer it will show the memory address in `fmt.Println(fmt.Sprintf...))`. If I de-reference the pointer in the log statement `*ptrInput` I get a panic if the pointer is nil.

Answer (score 1):

Some kind of recursive solution

```
package main

import "fmt"

type ListNode struct {
    Val  int
    Next *ListNode
}

func (l *ListNode) display() {
    if l != nil {
        fmt.Printf("%v ->", l.Val)
        l.Next.display()
    }
    fmt.Println()
}

func main() {
    num1 := &ListNode{2, &ListNode{4, &ListNode{3, nil}}}

    num1.display()
}
```